# parallel access to vectors

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, parallel-processing

I want to search a vector of strings `list` for strings that begin with a certain character `c`  and put the strings that I found in a second list `outputList`. This should happen on multiple threads.

I thought I just split the `list` to different threads and make the `outputList` a vector of string vectors, so that each thread has its own "`outputList`" and after every thread filled its own outputlist, I just flatten the vector of string vectors. However if I execute the binary it segfaults, except the words that are found are all in the last part of the `list` and therefore in the last vector of the `outputList`

loop that calls the threads:

```
    for (unsigned int nrThread = 0; nrThread < nrCpu; nrThread++)
    {
        outputList.push_back(std::vector<std::string>());
        int begin = std::accumulate(partSize, partSize + nrThread, 0);
        threadVector.emplace_back(searchList, list, c, begin, partSize[nrThread], &outputList[nrThread]);
    }
```

this function should run on different threads:

```
void searchList(std::vector<std::string> v, char c, unsigned int partBeginn, unsigned int partSize, std::vector<std::string> *outputList)
{
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = v.begin() + partBeginn;
    while (it != v.begin() + partBeginn + partSize)
    {
        if (it->at(0) == c)
        {
            outputList->push_back(*it);
        }
        it++;
    }
}
```

my assumption is that somehow the address `&outputList[nrThread]` of one subvector changes if an element is put in another subvector.

Any help to clarify this or tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `outputList.push_back(std::vector<std::string>());` has to reallocate the internal memory if it's not large enough. Any pointers to elements of it become dangling when this happens

Comment: Thank You! whats the best solution for this issue? Would  `std::vector::reserve`  solve this problem? I already know the maximum of found elements for each subvector is the size of the `list`/threads, or is there a more better or common way to solve something like this?

Comment: Pre-fill `outputList` before the loop where you create your threads. Based on the snippet you may even be able to do this when constructing it. Using `reserve` may work, but it's safer to just avoid using `push_back` after you push a pointer to an element into a different thread